# how to run while loop for some millisecond in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, time, timer, linux-kernel

i need to do some polling in Linux kernel for continues some time so i need to design while loop that exits after some milliseconds interval. So how can i do that?

I have though to use `gettimeofday()` but that can be used at user space i want this in kernel space.

Comment: this is not duplicate question...that question talk for userspace and i am about kernel space...that was for getting accurate time here i am interested in running while loop for some time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `msecs_to_jiffies` :

```
unsigned long j0,j1,delay;
delay = msecs_to_jiffies(20); /* 20 msec delay */
j0 = jiffies; 
j1 = j0 + delay; 

while (time_before(jiffies, j1)) 
        /* do something */
```

If you have high resolution timers on your system, you can use it for times in magnitude smaller than one jiffy. Generally consider using kernel timers or `hrt`.

- [high resolution timing in kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770353/high-resolution-timing-in-kernel)
- [IBM's tutorials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-timers-list/)

Answer (score -3):

You can use the `sleep` function, like `sleep(1)`: it will stop the activity for 1 sec.

Comment: Seconds are not milliseconds.